# bitnami version of WAMP is ignoring my.ini?

Tags: mysql, wamp, bitnami

I have installed bitnami's version of [WAMP](https://bitnami.com/stack/wamp/installer) on Windows 10 (bitnami-wampstack-7.1.28-0-windows-x64-installer)

Everything is working fine, except now I must move the data directory to another disk.  I changed my.ini as follows:

> ```
> datadir="D:/bitnami/data"
> ```

In accordance with http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,123685

I changed the header to :

```
[wampmysqld64]
```

It still doesn't work.

Why is the variable datadir not pointing MySQL to the new directory?

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the data of the wampmysqld section and rename the wampmysqld64 one to mysqld.

I just followed these steps to rename the folder and they worked.

- Stop MySQL
- Edit the datadir and log-error under the mysqld section

```
...
# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
...
# set datadir to the location of your data directory
datadir="D:/bitnami/data"
...
log-error="D:/bitnami/data/mysqld.log"
...
```

- Copy the content of the current data folder to the new one.
- Start MySQL again